# How to useEffect only if array length changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want update state only when prop "columns" length changed

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (columns.length !== prevColumns.length) {
      // update state
    }
  }, [columns]);
```

How can I do it?

Comment: where is your columns array coming from? if it's a state or from a prop then just passing `columns` array in the dependencies array will work, and every time you update column this effect will run

Comment: Are you sure that's the _only_ case though? What happens if an item in the array is modified?

Comment: Here's an example for you @James, https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-meadow-czm99?fontsize=14

Comment: @PrithweeDas I think you missed my point, in your example you are creating a brand new array and therefore a change is detected because React performs a shallow comparison. Try this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-http-hlc0t), this demonstrates my point (look at the log output when you click `do something`. Notice when the contents of the array are modified the UI isn't updated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can add the `length` property to the dependencies of `useEffect` hook instead of the array itself

```
useEffect(() => {
      // This code only fires on length change
}, [columns.length]);
```

And [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/so56968336-2c6c4)